# Property 'dataset' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' when I apply dataset to event.target

Tags: typescript

How do I make TypeScript happy regarding this error:

```
Property 'dataset' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'
```

I get it when I try to implement this code snippet:

```
document.addEventListener(
  "click",
  (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event !== null && event.target !== null) {
      const element = event.target as Element;
      if (element.matches(".dropdown-item.city")) {
        const cityName = event.target.dataset.value;
        console.log("City =", cityName);
        dropdown.classList.toggle("active");
      }
    }
  },
  false
);
```

Comment: Does `const element = event.target as HTMLElement;` work? (you would then have to do `const cityName = element.dataset.value;`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option rather than asserting the type is to check that the element is the right type in your conditional. In this case, I believe you want to make sure it's an `instanceof HTMLElement`.

```js
document.addEventListener(
  "click",
  (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event !== null && event.target instanceof HTMLElement) {
      const element = event.target;
      if (element.matches(".dropdown-item.city")) {
        const cityName = element.dataset.value;
        console.log("City =", cityName);
        dropdown.classList.toggle("active");
      }
    }
  },
  false
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by creating a custom dataset generic type that extends the native dataset type.

```
export type DatasetInjector<T, D extends DOMStringMap> = T & {
  dataset: D;
};
```

Now to showcase above custom generic let's assume I've two inputs (input, textaera) and each have custom attribute `inputId`. This is to identify which the input called the on change handler when we entered the password or confirm password.

```
const Input = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState({
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
  });

  const changeHandler: ChangeEventHandler<
    DatasetInjector<HTMLInputElement, { inputId: string }>
  > = (e) => {
    setValue((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.dataset.inputId]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const textareaChangeHandler: ChangeEventHandler<
    DatasetInjector<HTMLTextAreaElement, { inputId: string }>
    > = (e) => {
    setValue((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.dataset.inputId]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        data-input-id='password'
        onChange={changeHandler}
        value={value.password}
      />
      <textarea
        data-input-id='confirmPassword'
        onChange={textareaChangeHandler}
        value={value.confirmPassword}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

For more info see my article here [Reference link](https://app.weirdest.space/code-block/2022-11-property-dataset-does-not-exist-react-typescript-error)